# Grid Zoom - html5 canvas transformations not working

Tags: html, function, canvas, transformation

I'm very new to coding.  My project is to zoom in to an canvas image based on a 100px square.  My selector square is moving around the image successfully with the old squares deleted as I move around the grid.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="draw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="main">
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="600" style='border:3px solid red'>
</canvas>
</section>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function doFirst(){
    var x = document.getElementById('canvas')
    canvas=x.getContext('2d');
    canvas.strokeStyle = "blue";
    var pic= new Image();
    pic.src = "tut.jpg";
    pic.addEventListener ("load",function(){canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0)},false);

    }

    function select(e){
    var xPos=e.clientX;
    var yPos=e.clientY;

    var locationX = Math.floor(xPos/100)*100
    var locationY = Math.floor(yPos/100)*100
    var pic= new Image();
    pic.src = "tut.jpg";
    canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0);
    canvas.strokeRect(locationX,locationY,100,100);
    }

    function zoom (e) {
    var locationX = Math.floor(xPos/100)*100
    var locationY = Math.floor(yPos/100)*100

    canvas.translate(-locationX,-locationY);
    canvas.scale(5,5);
    }


    window.addEventListener ("load", doFirst, false);
    window.addEventListener ("mousemove", select, false);
    window.addEventListener("mousedown",zoom,false);
```

The zoom function doesn't kick in at all.  And I'm not sure how to move on from there next function - a simple colouring app -= rather than going back to the select function once it has - order functions is still a bit of a mystery.  Excuse any naivety as I've probably made some huge clangers in this code.

All help much appreciated,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question regarding `zoom()`:

Variables in JavaScript operate under function scope. That is, any variables declared in a function remain visible only to whatever's inside that function.

When you attempt to use `xPos` and `yPos` in `zoom()`, you will get `undefined` values for them because `xPos` and `yPos` are only declared inside `select()`.

`xPos` and `yPos` need to be declared and calculated in `zoom()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Of course!  Thank you. 
The zoom function seems a little harder to perfect than I thought: The scale seems to throw the offset out.

Also my animated square refreshed differently on Chrome and IE.  How strange.  Smooth on IE but flashes on Chrome.

Is there a good place to read up about creating a sequence of function events or do I just put one function inside the other?

Really appreciate your help,

Nick